# Passing in values to a JSON Post request

Tags: javascript, json, event-handling

My original issue was it was getting the value when the user clicked on the compose button but not the send button.

I have now changed it to use a different new function when the user clicks send.  However, now it's not doing anything.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I used the onclick method in the HTML and then created the function on my Javascript page.

HTML:

```
<div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form"
        method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="sendEmail" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
const element = document.getElementById('sendEmail');
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: 'card51short@gmail.com',
      subject: "buglets",
      body: 'Hes a fat one'
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      // Print result
      console.log(result);
  });
  });
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what is not working. Do you get any errors? Did you check that `fred` variable contains anything and not `undefined`?

Comment: it's blank.  No errors.

Comment: What does `console.log(fred)` print?

Comment: What do you mean by "not doing anything"?

Comment: it's not running the function as it's supposed to. Nothing happens. No errors. I changed my code again, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, in such cases you need to do an investigation of your code:

1. Check if `fred` is actually a string, and not `undefined`. Also, make it an explicit constant

```js
  const fred = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value // changed
  console.log(fred); // new

  fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: 'card51short@gmail.com',
      subject: fred,
      body: 'Hes a fat one'
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      // Print result
      console.log(result);
  });
```

2. If it's all good, do the next check of what is returned by the fetch:

```js
  const fred = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value

  fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: 'card51short@gmail.com',
      subject: fred,
      body: 'Hes a fat one'
    })
  })
  .then(response => { // edited
    console.log(response); // new
    return response.json() // edited
  }) // edited
  .then(result => {
      // Print result
      console.log(result);
  });
```

You should find what's not working by the end of this process

Comment: thank you. I changed my issue above if you can check that out.  I figured out why it was getting a blank element - it was getting the value of the element before the user filled it out.  Now I'm having a new issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

"value" attribute returns undefined for non input tags.
Try using innerHTML instead:

```
fred = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').innerHTML;
```

test your value for fred by cosole.log:

```
console.log(fred);
```

Comment: `innerHTML` won't return input's value. We don't know if `#compose-subject` is an input or not, but I'm guessing it is.

Comment: @robo robok I agree. Updated the response above.

Comment: the console log is completely empty. Shows nothing.

Comment: I think i know the issue.  The values are passed when the user clicks on compose email...not when they click on send email. so it's getting no values since it does the check immediately upon opening the compose email form.  I want it to get the values after the user clicks the send button

Comment: can u guys check out my new issue above? It's getting the function to run after they click the submit button. Thanks